# How to delete and create folder in a ec2 machine via python script?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, directory

I have a python script in an ec2 machine. The script should run everyday at the same time.
First part of the script: It deletes an existing directory (already exisiting in the ec2 machine)  and then creates a new empty directory.

I used the script before on my local machine and used this code and it worked:

```
shutil.rmtree("/my_directory")
os.mkdir("/my_directory")
```

Now trying to run it on the ec2 machine, i get the following error message

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I am making an assumption of several items,

I am assuming you are executing the script from the correct directory,

If you don't know this try,

```
import os
dirname, filename = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print(f"running from {dirname}")
print(f"file is {filename}")
```

similar to the bash `$ pwd` command

If you are running in the correct location it could be a race condition as the directory does not exist on the first run. Adding `ignore_errors=True` to the command can solve this. [Read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree)

```
shutil.rmtree('/folder_name', ignore_errors=True)
```

Last `/folder_name` is not writable. So you can test this multiple ways try a different location such as `/tmp/folder_name` or validate you can write to the location via `$ ls -la` and show the directory is writable. You would need to provide the output of this to also know this.

Comment: thx for the answer. I will try what you said, but i cant enter my ec2 machine anymore. First i have to solve this problem.